# SAS Loop through data to add labels in the style of "1.9, 1.10, 1.11" etc

Tags: sas

I'm running some SAS code on a table sorted by groups with multiple entries in each group. I want to give all the entries a unique identifier based on a sort order. For example:

```
Group   Item   Label
A        Z      1.1
A        Y      1.2
B        Z      2.1
B        Y      2.2
```

Many of the groups have more than 10 items, but I dont want the count to just roll over to the next integer value. What can I code that will keep the list going into things like 1.10 and 1.11 instead of going right to 2 after 1.9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use by-group processing and the sum statement to increment values: once for each group, and once for each item within the group. You can create a unique identifier variable named "label" by concatenating these two together and separating them with a `.`. Be sure it's sorted by `group` first.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by group;

    /* Increment the group label and reset the item num at the start
       of each group */
    if(first.group) then do;
        group_num+1;
        item_num=0;
    end;

    /* Increment the item number */
    item_num+1;

    label = cats(group_num, '.', item_num);

    drop group_num item_num;
run;
```

```
group   item    label
A       Z       1.1
A       Y       1.2
B       Z       2.1
B       Y       2.2
```